# Set a limit on While loop and sort by date

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sorting

I am wanting find a way I can set a limit to only show 1 row from a table and also show the 1 that is by the latest created date which is a column on the row also.

```
<?php

$q = "SELECT * FROM nots";
$r = mysqli_query($dbc, $q);

 while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($r)) {

     echo '<div style="background-color: red; box-sizing: border-box; padding: 20px; margin: 20px 10px; border-radius: 6px; color: #fff;">' . $row['not_name'] . '<br>'  . $row['not_content'] . '</div>';

 }

?>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you have an ID or date field of some sort you can use `ORDER BY [yourfieldname here] DESC` on that field to sort the return by the newest record first and then `LIMIT 1` to grab just that record

```
$q = "SELECT * 
     FROM nots
     ORDER BY ID DESC
     LIMIT 1";
```

Comment: Works perfectly I just changed your example of ID to created_date

Answer (score 4):

You do it in the query and then there is no need to loop since there is only one.  If `created_date` is the created date column:

```
$q = "SELECT * FROM nots ORDER BY created_date DESC LIMIT 1";
$r = mysqli_query($dbc, $q);
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($r);
```